# Change layout of Gboard (space between letters)

Tags: 7.0-nougat, gboard

I have installed Gboard on my Android 7 device. My keyboard looks now like following:

[image]

Is it possible to change the layout in something like the following? I mean the gaps between the characters, i.e. each letter should be in its own box.

[image]

Comment: If your device is rooted, you have a Magisk module for Gboard that offers plenty of alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change to another theme/layout in the settings.

[Here's a how-to guide.](https://www.goandroid.co.in/change-gboard-themes-custom-background/62170/)

If you want to build a completely custom keyboard that's more work but [also possible](https://www.androidauthority.com/lets-build-custom-keyboard-android-832362/).